# How can I fake dagger injection for Instrumented test in dynamic-feature modules?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, instrumented-test

I have a simple **Note Taking Application**.
The Application has an `app` *gradle module* and `editnote` *gradle dynamic feature-module*.

Hence my `editnote` gradle module will depend on `app` gradle module [because *feature-module* is not not resolved at the compile time]

My `app`  contains an `ApplicationModule` *dagger module* and `ApplicationComponent`.

Similarly my `editnote` contains `EditNoteModule` and `EditNoteComponent`.

```
@Module
open class EditNoteModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("TutorialText")
    open fun provideTutotialText(): String {
        return "(From Normal dagger module)This tutorial text gives a brief overview of how you can edit a text"
    }
}
```

```
@Component(
    modules = [ApplicationModule::class, EditNoteModule::class]
)
interface EditNoteComponent {
    fun inject(editNoteActivity: EditNoteActivity)
}
```

I am then injecting this `tutorialText` in `EditNoteActivity` like this.

```
class EditNoteActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Named("TutorialText")
    @Inject
    lateinit var tutorialText: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        DaggerEditNoteComponent.create()
            .inject(this)

        setContent {
            NoteTakingAppTheme {
                EditNoteScreen(
                    tutorialText = tutorialText,
                    onBackClick = { finish() }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to UI test this screen.
What I need is to provide my `TestEditNoteModule` and thereby a `testTutorialText`.

```
class TestEditNoteModule : EditNoteModule() {

    override fun provideTutorialText(): String {
        return "Tutorial text from the Test Edit Screen Module"
    }
}
```

What I tried so far -->

1. Create `CustomApplicationRunner`. But this only seems to fake the `TestApplicationModule` and `TestApplicationComponent`

```
class MyCustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {

    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, name: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, MyTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}

class MyTestApplication : NoteTakingApplication() {

    override fun initializeAppComponent(): ApplicationComponent {
        return DaggerTestApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(TestApplicationModule())
            .build()
    }
}
```

This is not helping with faking the `editnote` specific dagger. If you see in the Activity, I have no control over the `dagger late injection`. So my Activity is always initializing in the UI test with the Actual modules and component. -->

```
        DaggerEditNoteComponent.create()
            .inject(this)
```

Is there any way I can pass in my fake module and dependency to be injected in the Activity ?

Comment: Do u have a solution? I have this problem too

Comment: Unfortunately, no @freeman